# how to show the "max" attribute at oninvalid message?

Tags: php, html, variables, attributes

so, i had an input that have an max attribute on it, but i want to add oninvalid attribute that show a message of max. (lets say that the max is variate each input).

ex:

```html
<input type="number" max="(run function)" oninvalid="please enter the qty equal or less than (max attribute)">
```

sorry for my bad English, and my bad question. ty

Comment: If you want to do it in PHP, you need to manually check the value. PHP doesn't get the "max" value from the input. It only gets the actual value. If that's not your issue, then please edit your question and add more info since it's very unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If using jquery and max value as 10.
maybe this give you an idea

```js
 function check(input) {
  var maxnum = $("input").attr("max");
   if (input.value > maxnum) {
     input.setCustomValidity('Please enter the qty equal or less than (max attribute).');
   }else {
 // input is fine -- reset the error message
 input.setCustomValidity('Hooray');
   } 
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post">
  <b>Number Input (max number is 10):</b>
  <input type="number" min="0"  max = "10" name="number" value="" 
         oninput="check(this)" />
  <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this but you cannot solve it without a `<script>` tag

```js
function check(input) {
    const maxValue = parseInt(input.getAttribute('max'), 10);
    const currentValue = parseInt(input.value, 10);
    if (currentValue > maxValue) {
        input.setCustomValidity(`Maximum value is ${maxValue}`);
    }
}
```

```html
<form method="post">
    <input type="number" max="500" oninvalid="check(this)">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. There is a problem. After creating an error, if the correct value is entered, it will give an error again